# CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode() and CryptoServicesRegistrar.setApprovedOnlyMode(true) has been removed in bouncy castle

Tags: spring, security, bouncycastle

As the Title described, these two functions has been removed from bouncy castle v1.50, is there any alternative? I have to use v1.64 or above.

this is my code

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());
```

and I get the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode()Z
```

It seems like the BouncyCastleFipsProvider() call CryptoServicesRegistrar.isInApprovedOnlyMode() in its constructor, but there is no such function in this version, I don't know why it will call this method.
In order to fit the FedRamp, I have to use FIPSpovider.
Does anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two completely separate providers:

1. "BC", i.e. BouncyCastleProvider, the very widely used cryptography API, currently at version 1.70 ([website](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)).
2. "BCFIPS", i.e. BouncyCastleFipsProvider, a FIPS-compliant implementation of a more limited set of algorithms, currently at version 1.0.2.3 ([website](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html)).

These can't be used together. Also BCFIPS is not just a drop-in replacement for BC that suddenly makes your project FIPS-compliant. The great majority of users should be using BC.

The methods you mention are only relevant to BCFIPS, yet you are talking about version numbers that are only relevant to BC, which implies either that you are confused about which jars/provider you are trying to use, or that perhaps you are trying to use both in the same process, which doesn't work.

Comment: I have already exclude the BC in the pom, wouldn't it be ok to have these two together?
And, what do you mean by "Also BCFIPS is not just a drop-in replacement for BC that suddenly makes your project FIPS-compliant. The great majority of users should be using BC."
I have to use it to fit FIPS.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got the same issue in my company and i could resolve changing from
`Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleFipsProvider());`  to `Security.addProvider(OracleSecurityProvider.newBuilder());` also remove the `isOnlyApprovedMode property.`
and also and these dependencies because you'll sure get another
`NoSuchMethodError`

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
 <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
 <version>3.21.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
 <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
 <version>3.21.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this can help you